# Require command output in column format as below

Tags: ksh, aix

If i issue any command which contains more than one line, needs to print on right of screen but not below the echo message.

echo "My File deatails: `cat filename` "

what i want to get:-

My File Details : xxxxxx-file output-xxxxxxxx

```
             xxxxxx-file output-xxxxxxxx

             xxxxxx-file output-xxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this using *awk*:

```
    awk 'NR==1 {print "My File Details : ",$0} NR>1 {print "                  ",$0}' filename
```